# Do I need to add a db_index to this Django model?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django, indexing

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    content = models.ForeignKey(Content)
```

Do I need to add a db_index to "content"? Or would that automatically be indexed because it's a foreign key?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Unless specified otherwise, an index will be created for a `ForeignKey`.  Relevant source code:

```
class ForeignKey(RelatedField, Field):
    # snip
    def __init__(self, to, to_field=None, rel_class=ManyToOneRel, **kwargs):
        # snip
        if 'db_index' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['db_index'] = True
```

Comment: To disable creation of an index on a ForeignKey, set `db_index=False`: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13730